# Is it possible to show a boolean value in a checkbox or radio button on jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to show a checkbox or radio button checked or unchecked based on a boolean value.

Is there a way to do that on jsp pages?

I am using spring mvc 3.

Its like checked/unchecked options in an objective questions. If an option is true it should show a checkbox or radio button checked against it.

**EDIT**: The boolean value doesn't have anything to do with a form, its just a boolean value.

Thanks.

Comment: What does this checkbox should do? Do you use only on client via javascript or pass value to server too?

Comment: Nope, I am just displaying it. They're not being sent back to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<c:choose>
            <c:when test="${param.chk==true}">
                Checked <input type="checkbox" name="dance"
                       checked/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                Unchecked <input type="checkbox" name="dance"
                       />
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
```

Above I've shown it for request parameter chk, you can use it against any attribute in any scope.

Comment: You should mention that this uses JSTL

Answer (score 2):

If using JSTL (which is better to use than scriplets) go with XCoder's solution.

If just using JSP, you can do...

```
<% boolean x = true; %>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_name" <% if (x) { %> checked <% } %> />
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try approach described in spring mvc guide [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-formtaglib-formtag), **13.9.4. The checkbox tag**?

Comment: Yes I did, it doesn't work. I just have a boolean value (say "answer") in the database that needs to be displayed against something (say "option") that needs to be shown against it in a checkbox or radio botton. I don't have the data binding options in this situation. Say a class "Choice" has "option" and "answer" attributes and I have a a list of those Choice objects that I need to use to show in a checkbox (for "answer") and simple text (for "option") values.